# Spacemacs Unable to use dap mode for Spring Boot web app

Tags: spacemacs, java

I am trying to set up a break point in my controller so that I can debug my spring boot web application within spacemacs. Can someone walk me through the steps on doing this.

The steps I have done so far are

1. start up the spring boot application in debug mode with the 8000 port as the debug port. I did this by adding to my pom the following.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

2. execute the `mvn spring-boot:run` command. I have added the entire command run below with the logs. It does show 8000 port listening
3. `M-x dap-debug`
4. I select Java-Attach
5. I enter `8000` as the debug port

I have added an image of my controller that has breakpoints. One thing I notice is that in the bottom bar it shows `localhost(8000)  - pending`. So it seems that dap does not attach to the debug port.

I am not sure if this is relevant to this issue, but I am currently spacemacs develop branch.

```
~/P/b/backup02-after-hello-world-path-param λ mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------< com.in28minutes.rest.webservices:restful-web-services >--------
[INFO] Building restful-web-services 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ restful-web-services >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ restful-web-services ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ restful-web-services ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ restful-web-services ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory c:\Users\dmsil\Projects\backup02-after-hello-world-path-param\backup02-after-hello-world-path-param\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ restful-web-services ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ restful-web-services <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ restful-web-services ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
10:19:35.252 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
10:19:35.254 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
10:19:35.256 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/dmsil/Projects/backup02-after-hello-world-path-param/backup02-after-hello-world-path-param/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2020-03-21 10:19:35.590  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.r.w.r.RestfulWebServicesApplication  : Starting RestfulWebServicesApplication on DESKTOP-CQC5H52 with PID 10852 (C:\Users\dmsil\Projects\backup02-after-hello-world-path-param\backup02-after-hello-world-path-param\target\classes started by dmsil in c:\Users\dmsil\Projects\backup02-after-hello-world-path-param\backup02-after-hello-world-path-param)
2020-03-21 10:19:35.591  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.r.w.r.RestfulWebServicesApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-21 10:19:35.642  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2e66ae0c: startup date [Sat Mar 21 10:19:35 EDT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-03-21 10:19:37.086  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f29ac588] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-21 10:19:38.020  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-21 10:19:38.045  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-21 10:19:38.045  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2020-03-21 10:19:38.054  INFO 10852 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;c:\Windows\system32;c:\Windows;c:\Windows\System32\Wbem;c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;c:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;c:\Program Files\Git\cmd;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Users\dmsil\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.;c:\emacs-26.3-x86_64\libexec\emacs\26.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32;;.]
2020-03-21 10:19:38.158  INFO 10852 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-21 10:19:38.158  INFO 10852 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2518 ms
2020-03-21 10:19:38.339  INFO 10852 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2020-03-21 10:19:38.340  INFO 10852 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet webServlet mapped to [/h2-console/*]
2020-03-21 10:19:38.340  INFO 10852 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2020-03-21 10:19:38.344  INFO 10852 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2020-03-21 10:19:38.344  INFO 10852 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2020-03-21 10:19:38.344  INFO 10852 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2020-03-21 10:19:38.506  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-21 10:19:38.687  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-21 10:19:38.738  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-21 10:19:38.760  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2020-03-21 10:19:38.832  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
2020-03-21 10:19:38.836  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-03-21 10:19:38.881  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2020-03-21 10:19:39.005  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-03-21 10:19:39.265  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@27ee34'
2020-03-21 10:19:39.269  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-21 10:19:39.737  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2e66ae0c: startup date [Sat Mar 21 10:19:35 EDT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-03-21 10:19:39.813  WARN 10852 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-03-21 10:19:39.867  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/hello-world/path-variable/{name}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.in28minutes.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.HelloWorldBean com.in28minutes.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.HelloWorldController.helloWorldPathVariable(java.lang.String)
2020-03-21 10:19:39.868  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/hello-world],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.in28minutes.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.HelloWorldController.helloWorld()
2020-03-21 10:19:39.868  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/hello-world-bean],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.in28minutes.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.HelloWorldBean com.in28minutes.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.HelloWorldController.helloWorldBean()
2020-03-21 10:19:39.874  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2020-03-21 10:19:39.875  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2020-03-21 10:19:39.945  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2020-03-21 10:19:39.945  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2020-03-21 10:19:40.006  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2020-03-21 10:19:40.305  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-03-21 10:19:40.508  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2020-03-21 10:19:40.508  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2020-03-21 10:19:40.513  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2020-03-21 10:19:40.544  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-03-21 10:19:40.548  INFO 10852 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.r.w.r.RestfulWebServicesApplication  : Started RestfulWebServicesApplication in 5.279 seconds (JVM running for 5.795)
```

[image: Picture of my controller with breakpoints]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug in the dap java package that is preventing dap from running on Windows operating system.

I was able to run it successfully in mac os. I also assume it should work on Linux too.

I found a git ticket on this issue
https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/214

Hopefully someone will fix this bug in the future.